# Store a value current_timestamp + 1 hour in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, timestamp

I have a table in which there is a column toBeOffAt.
While adding a new entry I want to store this field as current_timestamp + 1 hour. Is there any easy way to do that in laravel?

```
$newUser->toBeOffAt = (current_timestamp + 1 hour?)
$newUser->save();
```

Comment: Check `date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($row['data'])+3600)`

Comment: I came up with another solution. $current = Carbon::now(); $newUser->toBeOffAt = $current->addHour();